# How do you remove more than one instance of a number in a BST in C?

Tags: c, recursion, binary-search-tree

I am creating a Binary Search Tree in C. I have my insertion, creation, pre-order, post-order, and in-order functions working.

However, I can't seem to figure out why my remove algorithm works only for the first instance of the number being removed. I understand that having my recursive calls first should traverse the tree backwards allowing me to search up the tree and remove the values as I see them and patch up the pointers but for some reason, the function only finds the first instance and then stops. Here's an example:

If my input in preorder is: 10 5 2 6 8 10 10 15 12 18 and I want to remove 10

```
+-----------+------------------+-------------------------+
|   Type    |     Expected     |         Actual          |
+-----------+------------------+-------------------------+
| Preorder  | 5 2 6 8 15 12 18 | 5 2 6 8 10 10 15 12 18  |
| Inorder   | 2 5 6 8 12 15 18 | 2 6 8 5 12 15 18        |
| Postorder | 2 12 18 15 8 6 5 | 8 6 2 12 18 15 5        |
+-----------+------------------+-------------------------+
```

It's obvious that it only removed the first instance of 10 and then returned the root. How do I go about finding the other instances and removing them as well? I understand the structure of the tree after the removal calls but I'm not so sure as to why my removal function isn't doing what I've drawn out on paper.

Here's the code:

Main.c

```
#include "Header.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    char command[100];
    int value=0,input=0;
    treeNode *new_node, *root;
    root=NULL;

    while(scanf("%s", command) > 0){
        if(strcmp(command, "insert") == 0){
            new_node=create_node();
            scanf("%d",&value);
            new_node->e=value;
            if(root==NULL){
                root=create_node();
                root->e=value;
            }else
                insert(root, new_node);
        }else if(strcmp(command, "remove") == 0){
            scanf("%d",&input);
            if(root==NULL)
                printf("Tree Is Empty\n");
            else
                root=removal(root, input);
        }else if(strcmp(command, "postorder") == 0){
            if(root==NULL)
                printf("Tree Is Empty\n");
            else{
                post_order(root);
                printf("\n");
            }
        }else if(strcmp(command, "preorder") == 0){
            if(root==NULL)
                printf("Tree Is Empty\n");
            else{
                pre_order(root);
                printf("\n");
            }
        }else if(strcmp(command, "inorder") == 0){
            if(root==NULL)
                printf("Tree Is Empty\n");
            else{
                in_order(root);
                printf("\n");
            }
        }else if(strcmp(command, "calculate") == 0){
            calculate(root);
        }
        else if(strcmp(command, "clear") == 0){
            root=clear_tree(root);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Header.H

```
#ifndef Header_h
#define Header_h

#include "stdheader.h"

/*stdheader.h is just a header file with the standard headers in it like stdout etc...*/

typedef int element;
typedef struct treeNode treeNode;

struct treeNode{
    element e;
    element count;
    struct treeNode* Left;
    struct treeNode* Right;
};

treeNode* create_node();
void insert(treeNode*,treeNode*);
treeNode* findMin(treeNode*);
treeNode* removal(treeNode*,element);
void post_order(treeNode*);
void pre_order(treeNode*);
void in_order(treeNode*);
void calculate(treeNode*);
int rec_calculate(treeNode*);
treeNode* clear_tree(treeNode*);


#endif /* Header_h */
```

Function.c

```
#include "Header.h"

treeNode* create_node(){
    treeNode *t=(treeNode*)malloc(sizeof(treeNode));
    t->Left=t->Right=NULL;
    t->count=1;
    return t;
}

void insert(treeNode* root,treeNode* new_node){
    if (new_node->e <= root->e) {
        if (root->Left == NULL)
            root->Left = new_node;
        else
            insert(root->Left, new_node);
    }

    if (new_node->e > root->e) {
        if (root->Right == NULL)
            root->Right = new_node;
        else
            insert(root->Right, new_node);
    }
}

void in_order(treeNode *temp) {
    if (temp != NULL) {
        in_order(temp->Left);
        printf("%d ", temp->e);
        in_order(temp->Right);
    }
}

void pre_order(treeNode *temp) {
    if (temp != NULL) {
        printf("%d ", temp->e);
        pre_order(temp->Left);
        pre_order(temp->Right);
    }
}

void post_order(treeNode *temp) {
    if (temp != NULL) {
        post_order(temp->Left);
        post_order(temp->Right);
        printf("%d ", temp->e);
    }
}

treeNode* findMin(treeNode* node)
{
    treeNode* current = node;

    while (current->Left != NULL)
        current = current->Left;

    return current;
}

treeNode* removal(treeNode* root, element e)
{
    if (root == NULL)
        return root;

    if (e < root->e)
        root->Left = removal(root->Left, e);

    else if (e > root->e)
        root->Right = removal(root->Right, e);

    else
    {
        if (root->Left == NULL)
        {
            treeNode *temp = root->Right;
            free(root);
            return temp;
        }
        else if (root->Right == NULL)
        {
            treeNode *temp = root->Left;
            free(root);
            return temp;
        }
        treeNode* temp = root->Left;
        root->e = temp->e;
        root->Left = removal(root->Left, temp->e);
    }
    return root;
}

void calculate(treeNode *root){
    int value;
    if (root == NULL){
        printf("Tree Is Empty\n");
    }
    else if(root->Left==NULL&&root->Right==NULL)
        printf("%d\n",root->e);

    else{
        value=rec_calculate(root);
        printf("%d\n",value);
    }
}

int rec_calculate(treeNode *root){
    int A=0,B=0;

    if (root == NULL)
        return 0;
    if(root->Left==NULL&&root->Right==NULL)
        return root->e;
    A=rec_calculate(root->Left);
    B=rec_calculate(root->Right);
    return (root->e)*(A-B);
}

treeNode* clear_tree( treeNode* root )
{
        if(root) {
            clear_tree(root->Left);
            root->Left=NULL;
            clear_tree(root->Right);
            root->Right=NULL;
            root=NULL;
            free(root);
        }
    return root;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two bugs here, both lie in this block of your `removal` function:

```
treeNode* temp = root->Left;
root->e = temp->e;
root->Left = removal(root->Left, temp->e);
```

You remove the old value of `root->Left`, but there may still be duplicate values in the left sub-tree. You need a second `removal` call that removes the element that was originally searched for.

In addition, `root->Left` may not be the correct replacement element. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree#Deletion) describes BST deletion this way:

> Deleting a node with two children: call the node to be deleted N. Do not delete N. Instead, choose either its in-order successor node or its in-order predecessor node, R. Copy the value of R to N, then recursively call delete on R until reaching one of the first two cases. If you choose in-order successor of a node, as right sub tree is not NIL (Our present case is node has 2 children), then its in-order successor is node with least value in its right sub tree, which will have at a maximum of 1 sub tree, so deleting it would fall in one of first 2 cases.

Note that the in-order predecessor node is not just the left child, but the right-most leaf of the left child. So you need to find that node, and use its value instead of just grabbing the value of the left child.

The following listing shows a working `removal` function and a helper function to find the predecessor element:

```
element predecessor(treeNode* root)
{
    // Note: This function should only be called for
    //       a root that has a non-null left sub-tree.
    treeNode* n = root->Left;
    while(n->Right != NULL)
    {
        n = n->Right;
    }
    return n->e;
}

treeNode* removal(treeNode* root, element e)
{
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    if (e < root->e)
    {
        root->Left = removal(root->Left, e);
        return root;
    }
    else if (e > root->e)
    {
        root->Right = removal(root->Right, e);
        return root;
    }
    else
    {
        if (root->Left == NULL)
        {
            treeNode *temp = root->Right;
            free(root);
            return temp;
        }
        else if (root->Right == NULL)
        {
            treeNode *temp = removal(root->Left, e);
            free(root);
            return temp;
        }
        else
        {
            // Remove duplicate values first!
            root->Left = removal(root->Left, e);
            element replacement_e = predecessor(root);
            root->e = replacement_e;
            root->Left = removal(root->Left, replacement_e);
            return root;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! There's still a problem though and I forgot to mention this in my original post, when I call postorder and inorder it's still printing out incorrectly. I've updated the post since then @Jason Watkins

Comment: I've updated my answer above to address another bug I overlooked in my initial answer. This should fix your in-order traversal. I don't think your expected post-order list is correct. The expected post-order traversal order should be `2 6 5 12 18 15 8`.